# Could not find the matching Number in mongodb aggregation using Regex

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection

//demo name : user_informations

```
  {
        "_id" : 3015,
        "Phone Number" : "9159571195",
        "First Name" : "logesh",
        "Last Name" : "chandiran",
        "Email ID" : "logu@gmail.com",
        "Gender" : "male",
        "customerID" : "CUST3015",
        "createddate" : 1472482064363.0,
        "modifieddate" : 1474384997049.0,
        "transationHistory" : [ 
            {
                "transactionStatus" : "Success",
                "transactionAmount" : 2500,
                "paymentId" : "Q8urVX9Cpf",
                "transactionDate" : 1472754600000.0,
                "transactionId" : "7egsOpmqBR",
                "comments" : "EMI",
                "medium" : "Cash"]
            }
    }
```

i'm using the following query

```
db.user_informations.aggregate([
           {
            $match:{"Phone Number": '9159571195'}},
            {$unwind:'$transationHistory'},
            {"$match":{"$or":[
            {"transationHistory.transactionAmount":{$regex:/2500/i}},
            {"transationHistory.transactionId":{$regex:/2500/i}},
            {"transationHistory.paymentId":{$regex:/2500/i}},
            {"transationHistory.transactionStatus":{$regex:/2500/i}},
            {"transationHistory.medium":{$regex:/2500/i}},
            {"transationHistory.comments":{$regex:/2500/i}}
            ]}},
            {"$group":{_id: null,"count":{$sum: 1 },"result":{$push:"$transationHistory"}}}

         ])
```

The above query works fine with values in string but not with numbers it is returning as null. How to match the value with numbers in collection fields.
I need the count and result of matching data from the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.user_informations.aggregate(
    {$match:{"Phone Number": '9159571195'}},
    {$unwind:'$transationHistory'},
{$project:{
            "transactionAmount":{ "$toLower":"$transationHistory.transactionAmount"}                            
            }},
    {"$match":{
        "$or":[
             {"transactionAmount":{$regex:txt,"$options": "i"}}
        ]
    },
    {"$group":{
        _id: null,
        "count":{$sum: 1 }
    }})
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a tool for strings, not numbers. Use regular number comparison operators, like `$eq`, `$gt`, `$lt`, etc.

Basically, it'll be:

```
db.user_informations.aggregate(
    {$match:{"Phone Number": '9159571195'}},
    {$unwind:'$transationHistory'},
    {"$match":{
        "$or":[
            {"transationHistory.transactionAmount":{$eq:2500}}
        ]
    },
    {"$group":{
        _id: null,
        "count":{$sum: 1 },
        "result":{$push:"$transationHistory"}
    }})
```

Hopefully, all brackets are in place.

Comment: Is there any way to match digit in numbers like input 2 return 200 number